# Ratchet PHP Websocket Library works fine but causing HTTP code 503 Service unavailable after running for for a few days

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I am using Ratchet for Websockets in my application. I am running the Websocket server in supervisor. The application runs well for sometime even when there is high traffic but after some time the server responds with a 503 service unavailable error when I try to access the application in the browser until I restart supervisor and It runs fine again for some time. This happens at times when there is low traffic to the sever so I do not think it a traffic problem.

Could I have missed a configuration somewhere during deployment of Ratchet because it is the only program that I am running in supervisor.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding gc_collect_cycles() to the onClose function.

My code now looks like this:

```
<?php
//Pusher
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface 
{
    //Array of channels with connected clients
    protected $subscribed_channels= array();
    protected $clients=array();
    protected $connections;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->connections = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    //Accepts client connections and adds the channel subscribed to in the subscribed channels
    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $channel) 
    {
        $channel_id=$channel->getId();
        $this->subscribed_channels[$channel_id] = $channel;
        $connection_id=$conn->resourceId;
        $this->clients[$connection_id]=array('channel'=>$channel);
        $channel_subscriptions=$channel->count();
        //echo "Client {$connection_id} has subscribed to {$channel_id} channel. {$channel_subscriptions} Cleints Subscribed \n";
    }

    //Accepts data as json containing the channel being pushed to, and the data being pushed.
    public function onPush($request) 
    {
        $request_array = json_decode($request, true);

        if(!isset($request_array['channel']))
        {
            echo"Channel not sent by app \n";
            return;
        }
        //Check if data has been sent by app
        if(!isset($request_array['data']))
        {
            echo"Data not sent by app \n";
            return;
        }
        // If the channel being pushed to has no subscribers, don't push
        if (!array_key_exists($request_array['channel'], $this->subscribed_channels)) 
        {
            echo"{$request_array['channel']} channel has no subscribers \n";
            return;
        }

        $channel = $this->subscribed_channels[$request_array['channel']];

        // Foward the request to all the subscribers in the channel
        $data=json_encode($request_array['data']);
        $channel->broadcast($data);
        //echo "Pushing data to {$request_array['channel']} channel at ".strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')."\n";
    }

    public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $channel) 
    {
        $connection_id=$conn->resourceId;
        $channel_id=$channel->getId();
        $channel_subscriptions=$channel->count()-1;
        if($channel_subscriptions==0)
        {
            unset($this->subscribed_channels[$channel_id]);
        }
        //echo "Client {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected from {$channel_id} channel. {$channel_subscriptions} Clients subscribed \n";
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->connections->attach($conn);
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $connection_id=$conn->resourceId;
        $channel=$this->clients[$connection_id]['channel'];
        unset($this->clients[$connection_id]);
        $this->onUnSubscribe($conn,$channel);
        $this->connections->detach($conn);
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
    public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $channel, array $params) 
    {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->callError($id, $channel, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
    }
    public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $channel, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) 
    {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->close();
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    }
}
```

```
//Web socket server code
<?php
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

    // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onPush'));

    //Replace the variables $my_ip and $my_port with your server $ip and $port.

    $webSock = new React\Socket\Server('$my_ip:$my_port', $loop);
    $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
```

```
//My php app code
//You will need the zmq php module in your php for this to work
function push_to_socket($channel,$data)
{
  $message = array(
    'channel' => $channel
  , 'data'    => $data
 );
 $context = new ZMQContext();
 $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
 $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
 $socket->send(json_encode($message));
}
```

```
//My Javascript code
//You need AutobahnJS for this to work.
//You might also need jQuery or else modify the code to eliminate jQuery syntax
//Replace 'channel' with a channel/topic name you want to use.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(get_connected);

    function get_connected()
    {
        var hasWs = 'WebSocket' in window || 'MozWebSocket' in window;
        if (hasWs) 
        {
                conn = new ab.Session('wss:{my_domain}/wss',
                function() 
                {
                    conn.subscribe('channel', function(topic,message){
                        //Process your message
                    });
                },
                function() {
                    //console.warn('Connection closed'); 
                    get_connected();  
                },
                {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
            );
        }
    }


</script>
```